# Ngrok Redirecting To Welcome Rails Page With Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ngrok

I'm running my project on the domain http://app.lvh.me locally and it works fine.

I'm running this command with ngrok:

```
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite --request-header-remove 'referer' app.lvh.me:3000
```

And the result is Ngrok forwarding like this:

```
Forwarding                    https://(mylinkhere).ngrok.io -> http://app.lvh.me:3000
```

When I go to the link that ngrok gave me, it doesn't redirect me to `app.lvh.me` but instead it seems to redirect to `lvh.me` since all I see is the welcome rails page.

I've been going at this for a few hours and read every thread but can't find the solution.

Please help, thank you

Comment: Dealing with the same issue! Any shot you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same issue and was able to solve it with:

```
ngrok http --subdomain <my_subdomain> --host-header=rewrite https://api.<my_domain>.com
```

**Update Nov 2023**: `--subdomain` has been deprecated. The appropriate command is now:

```
ngrok http --domain <my_subdomain> --host-header=rewrite https://api.<my_domain>.com
```

Comment: An update: 
flag --subdomain has been deprecated